# Neumann RSM-191 - Can I use a Sound Devices 302 as a substitute for the MTX Box?

Tags: microphone, field-recording, preamp, mid-side

I've found a good deal on a Neumann RSM-191 stereo shotgun. It's just the mic alone - no cables or the proprietary MTX preamp box.

Since the 302 mixer can do M/S decoding, could I just use that in place of the Neumann preamp? Or would I still be missing some essential features?

Answer (score 2):

The MTX isn't just a matrix box that you could do on a mixer but actually the power supply of the microphone. Think it like two neumann km100 bodies for two ak20+ak40 capsules. The signals that the rsm alone is outputing or inputting from the DIN connector, according to my manual are

1. -50 V
2. +50 V
3. Side
4. Mid
5. GND
6. +10 V
7. N/C

So nothing like Mid Hot-Cold-GND and Side Hot-Cold-GND as you expect to feed a mixer with it